# Extracting Person Names from a text data in German Language using spacy or nltk?

Tags: text, corpus, named-entity-recognition

I am using a spacy model for german language for extracting named entities such as location names, person names and company names but not getting the proper result as an output. Is there any missing concept which I am unable to figure out precisely.

```
def city_finder(text_data):
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    doc = nlp(text_data)
    for ents in doc.ents:
        if(ents.label_ == 'GPE'):
            return (ents.text)
```

This is the code which I had used in order to find the city names from the text data but its accuracy is not very high. When I run this code the result is coming out to be something else instead of the city name. Is there something which I am missing out as part of the Natural Language Processing or any other area?

Answer (score 1):

There are standard libraries available for extracting language specific POS. You can check other libraries for extracting nouns for example Pattern library from CLiPS (refer https://github.com/clips/pattern) implements POS for languages like German and Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load a German language model, currently you loaded an English language model (see the prefix "en"). There are two German models available:

- de_core_news_sm
- de_core_news_md

Source: https://spacy.io/models/de

You can install them via the following command:

```
python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm
```

However, there are currently only four different entities supported (and my experience is that without retraining, the entity extraction doesn't work very well in German)

> Supported NER: LOC, MISC, ORG, PER

You would have to adapt your code the following way:

```
def city_finder(text_data):
    nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm') # load German language model
    doc = nlp(text_data)
    for ents in doc.ents:
        if(ents.label_ == 'LOC'): # GPE is not supported
            return (ents.text)
```